# Division of two static integers always returning 0% ratio

Tags: java, eclipse

My code:

```
public class Test {

public static int l = 29;
public static int w = 16;
public static int total = w + l;
public static int result = w / total;
public static int Result = total * 100;

 public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("You're W/L ratio is: " + (Result) + "%"); // Display the string.
 }
}
```

Response in console: *You're W/L ratio is: 0%*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the calculation by casting `w` and `total` to `double`, or just make them `double` to begin with. For the first option:

```
public static double result = (double)w / (double)total;
```

Answer (score 2):

You're doing int division which always returns an int and so `w / total` will always be 0 since total is always greater than w. Do the multiplication by 100 first.

```
int result = (w * 100) / total;
```

Also you will want to learn and use java naming rules. Variable names should begin with a lower case letter.

Answer (score 1):

whenever you do division when both numbers are integers, in result you will get integer in return.

which actually means you will get floor value of (a/b); ie:

> 1/2=0 as 1/2=> 0.5> floor of 0.5= 0;
>
> 3/4=0 as 3/4=> 0.75> floor of 0.75= 0;

etc